# How to pass Bitmap image to a sectioned ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, textview

I have successfully implemented **sectioned listview**, but now I'm facing a problem i.e. each row in `ListView` has some `Textview` plus `ImageView`.
The image in `ImageView` is only displayed when I use `R.drawalbe.myimage` i.e. when I assign an *integer id*. 
But it doesn't work when I actually assign an Bitmap or Drawable. Basically these bitmaps are downloaded from internet, how can I make then appear in sectioned `ListView`.

```
     // this works
      security.add(createItem(v1, v2, v3, v4, v6, R.drawable.add));                 

     // this doesnt work
     Bitmap b; // loaded from somewhere
      security.add(createItem(v1, v2, v3, v4, v6, b));

   public Map<String, ?> createItem(String title, String caption, String date, String hrs, String lnk, int obj)
{
    Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
    item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);
    item.put(ITEM_DATE, date);
    item.put(VISIBLE_DATE, hrs);
    item.put(LINK, lnk);
    item.put(IMAGE, obj);

    return item;
}
```

Comment: You can use this to load images in ListView directly: [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: so you just need to put WebURL of image(instead of bitmap object) in the Hashmap.

Comment: Sorry bro..its not working, can u plz suggest me some other method. Even when i downloaded images and passed to it, it didnt work.

Comment: no need to pass downloaded images, just a URL can work.

Comment: i am passing bitmap, but now i got this error 06-18 11:34:56.779: I/System.out(1167): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@406892f8. Can you plz tell me why uri is showing this error.

Comment: i beleive your solution did worked for me, but still i am getting this error 06-18 11:56:27.159: I/System.out(513): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@405e06f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this String.valueOf rather then what you are using it now, it would always fail if you use the current code.